# React clone/create Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a library (antUI) when I can pass a component inside a configuration like this:

```
const configuration = [{
  render: record => <Component record={record} />
}]
```

I want to modify that configuration using `.map` function:

```
const additionalProps = { someProp: 'value' };
configuration.map(el => ({
    render: el.render, // React.cloneElement? React.createElement?
}));
```

so I can pass additional prop to the `Component`. Is there a way to do this? I've been trying with `React.cloneElement` and `React.createElement` but got nothing but errors.

Answer (score 1):

Good God, I was adding `()` at the end of my code unnecessarily.

It should look like:

```
const additionalProps = { someProp: 'value' };
configuration.map((el) => {
    const copy = { ...el };
    return {
        ...el,
        render: record => React.cloneElement(copy.render(record), additionalProps),
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass them to the component  ?

```
const additionalProps = { someProp: 'value' };
const configuration = [{
    render: record => <Component record={record} {...additionalProps} />
}]
```